# Oracle SQL: Checking customer recency by month

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

I have an order_list table for an eCommerce site from which i need to create a report on how many customers purchased in a month. Out of these customers, how many were first time customers, how many had placed an order within the last 90 days, how many within the last 180 days, etc.

The finished report would be an excel grid that looked like this:

[image: Recency Grid Example]

This is the query i have right now:

```
SELECT months.month,
       count(distinct(case when months.month = Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH') then orders.email_address else null end)) as total_monthly_orders,
       count(distinct(case when months.month = Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH') and order_rank = 1 then orders.email_address else null end)) as monthly_first_purchasers,

       /* This is the logic thats not working right now*/
       /*count(distinct(case when (months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) <= 92 then orders.email_address else null end)) as less_than_3_month_purchasers,
       count(distinct(case when (months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) <= 181 then orders.email_address else null end)) as less_than_6_month_purchasers,
       count(distinct(case when (months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) <= 273 then orders.email_address else null end)) as less_than_9_month_purchasers,
       count(distinct(case when (months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) <= 365 then orders.email_address else null end)) as less_than_12_month_purchasers,
       count(distinct(case when (months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) > 365 then orders.email_address else null end)) as one_year_plus_purchasers*/


FROM (  SELECT Trunc (TO_DATE (A.create_date), 'MONTH') AS month
            FROM ORDER_DETAIL A
           WHERE TO_DATE (A.create_date) >= '1-Jan-2018'
        GROUP BY Trunc (TO_DATE (A.create_date), 'MONTH')
        ORDER BY Trunc (TO_DATE (A.create_date), 'MONTH') ASC) months
INNER JOIN (SELECT A.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
               A.DEMANDWARE_ORDER_NUMBER AS order_id,
               TO_DATE (A.CREATE_DATE) AS order_date,
               RANK ()
               OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMAIL_ADDRESS
                     ORDER BY A.DEMANDWARE_ORDER_NUMBER ASC)
                  AS Order_rank
          FROM ORDER_DETAIL A
         WHERE A.email_address IS NOT NULL) orders
          ON months.month >= Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH')

Group by months.month
Order by months.month ASC
```

I tested the query and its correctly pulling the total customers and first time customers. But i can't figure out how to pull the customers whose last purchase would be within the last 3 months / 6 months / etc.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Edit: Adding sample data
[image: Current Query Output]

I've checked against other queries and the values in the total customer & first time customer columns are correct. But the values in the other columns are incorrect. Essentially, to test this, the sum of the customers in every bucket should be equal to the number of total customers.

For example: if we had 34,016 customers in total in Jan, we couldn't have 166,148 customers in the <3 Months bucket

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: If the customer had 2 orders in the last 3 months does it count as 1 or 2?

Comment: Also, how do you want year overlaps handled? Are you just considering 2018? If I order in Feb 2018 and December 2017 do I count as within 3 months? (HINT-HINT-NUDGE-NUDGE!!!!!!! This is why sample data is so important)

Comment: I don't get it. If I ordered something yesterday (2nd of August 2018), I have placed an order this month. I have also placed an order witin the last 90 days, and within the last 180 days, ... So all columns would show the same figure. I suppose you want something different, but what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this right this might give you the gist. Create a binary flag for whether the last order was within the last few months the sum up the distincts.

This won't really work if the order dates span multiple years, so it'll break once you get to 2019. But that's an easy fix. I can't really tell how you want multiple years handled.

```
SELECT order_month,
       SUM(first_order) AS customerWithFirstOrder,
       SUM(within_three_months) AS customersWithinThreeMonths,
       SUM(within_six_months) AS customersWithinSixMonths
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
               customer,
               case when prev_order_date IS NULL THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END first_order,
               case when prev_order_date >= DATE_ADD(month,order_month,-3) IS NULL 
                         THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                END within_three_months,
               case when prev_order_date >= DATE_ADD(month,order_month,-6) IS NULL 
                         THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
               END within_six_months,
               TRUNC(order_date, 'MONTH') order_month
          FROM (SELECT  LAG(TO_DATE(create_date)) OVER
                     (  PARTITION BY customer
                            ORDER BY TO_DATE(create_date)
                     )  AS prev_order_date,
                       customer,
                       TO_DATE(create_date) order_Date
                  FROM ORDER_DETAIL
                 WHERE TO_DATE (A.create_date) >= '1-Jan-2018'
               ) TMP
       );
```

Comment: I got it to work with this. That Lag keyword is exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your `CASE WHEN` need to check month number instead of day number.

```
(months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) <= 3
```

instead of

```
(months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) <= 92
```

Then you need to add query a column in your `month` subquery, to judgment over one year.

use `EXTRACT` from `order_date` colnum.

```
(EXTRACT(year FROM months.order_date) - EXTRACT(year FROM orders.order_date)) > 0
```

The query might be like this.

```
SELECT months.month,
       count(distinct(case when months.month = Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH') then orders.email_address else null end)) as total_monthly_orders,
       count(distinct(case when months.month = Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH') and order_rank = 1 then orders.email_address else null end)) as monthly_first_purchasers,
       count(distinct(case when (months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) <= 3 then orders.email_address else null end)) as less_than_3_month_purchasers,
       count(distinct(case when (months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) <= 6 then orders.email_address else null end)) as less_than_6_month_purchasers,
       count(distinct(case when (months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) <= 9 then orders.email_address else null end)) as less_than_9_month_purchasers,
       count(distinct(case when (months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH'))) <= 12 then orders.email_address else null end)) as less_than_12_month_purchasers,
       count(distinct(case when (EXTRACT(year FROM months.order_date) - EXTRACT(year FROM orders.order_date)) > 0 then orders.email_address else null end)) as one_year_plus_purchasers
FROM (  SELECT Trunc (TO_DATE (A.create_date), 'MONTH') AS month,
               TO_DATE (A.CREATE_DATE) order_date
            FROM ORDER_DETAIL A
           WHERE TO_DATE (A.create_date) >= '1-Jan-2018'
        GROUP BY Trunc (TO_DATE (A.create_date), 'MONTH')
        ORDER BY Trunc (TO_DATE (A.create_date), 'MONTH') ASC) months
INNER JOIN (SELECT A.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
               A.DEMANDWARE_ORDER_NUMBER AS order_id,
               TO_DATE (A.CREATE_DATE) AS order_date,
               RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY A.EMAIL_ADDRESS ORDER BY A.DEMANDWARE_ORDER_NUMBER ASC) AS Order_rank
          FROM ORDER_DETAIL A
         WHERE A.email_address IS NOT NULL
         ) orders
          ON months.month >= Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH')
Group by months.month
Order by months.month ASC
```

Comment: I used the month difference initially, but then realized that the difference between dates is coming in days when i use: (months.month - (Trunc (orders.order_date, 'MONTH')). That's why i added those numbers, instead of month numbers.

Comment: You can try to use `EXTRACT` to instead it. `(EXTRACT(month FROM months.order_date) - EXTRACT(month FROM orders.order_date))`

Answer (score 0):

I created a dummy table according to user use case and wrote a query according to your requirement. query is very straight forward. No need of joining the table 2 times.
below is my code.

-- Table creation

```
create table ORDER_DETAIL
(
create_date date, -- date on which customer created account.
EMAIL_ADDRESS varchar2(100),
DEMANDWARE_ORDER_NUMBER number, -- orderid
order_date date
);
```

-- Inserting data

```
insert into ORDER_DETAIL values (to_date('1-JAN-2018'),'xyz@gmail.com',1,sysdate);
insert into ORDER_DETAIL values (to_date('31-JAN-2018'),'xyz@gmail.com',4,sysdate);
insert into ORDER_DETAIL values (to_date('3-MAR-2018'),'xyz@gmail.com',2,sysdate-8);
```

-- query

```
select 
count(*) as count_per_month,
to_char(CREATE_DATE,'MON') as customer_perchase_month,
sum((case 
    when to_char(CREATE_DATE,'MON') = to_char(ORDER_DATE,'MON')
    then
        1
    else
        0
    end ))First_Time_Customer, 
sum((case
    when months_between(trunc(ORDER_DATE) , trunc(CREATE_DATE)) < 3 then
        1
    else
        0
   end )) less_than_3_months,

sum((case
    when months_between((trunc(ORDER_DATE)) , trunc(CREATE_DATE)) between 3 and 6  then
        1
    else
        0
   end )) less_than_6_months , 

sum((case
    when months_between((trunc(ORDER_DATE)) , trunc(CREATE_DATE)) between 6 and 12  then
        1
    else
        0
   end )) less_than_12_months,

   sum((case
    when months_between(trunc(ORDER_DATE) , trunc(CREATE_DATE)) > 12 then
        1
    else
        0
   end )) greater_than_12 

from
ORDER_DETAIL od
WHERE TO_DATE (create_date) >= '1-Jan-2018'
and EMAIL_ADDRESS is not null
group by to_char(CREATE_DATE,'MON');
```

Hope this solve your requirement.

Regards Ankit.

Comment: Hi Ankit, this is very interesting. The issue that i'm facing is that customer account creation date has no correlation with the day they place orders on. For example, i have to look at all customers who purchased in July 2018 and be able to say that that 1/2 of these customers were first time purchasers while 10% had purchased within the last 3 months. Let me know if this makes sense. And thanks again!

Comment: Hi @abhay , what is your logic to identify first time customer ??